# How to add multiple conditions for the values present in a single column and display the result in separate columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has a similar structure as below.

| number | status |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | failed |
| 456 | failed |
| 123 | success |
| 789 | failed |
| 789 | success |
| 456 | success |
| 123 | success |

I need to write a query that would give me a result like the following:

| number | total_occurence | failed_count | success_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 456 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 789 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: please avoid pasting screenshots, please rollback to the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is hhow you can do it:

```
select number 
       , count(*) total
       , count(case when status = 'fail' then 1 end) fail_count
       , count(case when status = 'success' then 1 end) success_count
from yourtable
group by number
```

Comment: Thanks, bro! It worked like a charm. 

Could you recommend me sources from where I can learn SQL in detail. I know SQL but my knowledge is shallow.

Comment: @SyedKamranAhmed you are welcome , well there are a lot of free resources out there ,if you google it , I'm not familiar with any in specific